# Regex for pattern with hyphens

Tags: regex

Is there a regex in Java that allows alphanumeric characters (both upper and lower case), has to start with a letter, could end with a letter or a digit and also contain hyphens in the middle?

I have ^[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9-]$ but not sure if it could work for all cases.

Comment: Hi Niv! Can you tell us what language(s) or frameworks you're using? Different ones allow different regexes, and the type you're referring to would be dependent on that information.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?$
```

- `^[A-Za-z]`: starting with a letter
- `(...)?$`: optionally followed by this group, and end in it
- `[A-Za-z0-9-]*`: any number of letters, digits and hyphens
- `[A-Za-z0-9]`: one letter or digit

You need point 2 or you'll miss single-letter sequences, which are also valid accorrdding to your description

With Python, I do this:

```
(?i)^[a-z]([a-z\d-][a-z\d])?$
```

Comment: Better to use case-insensitive flag, and you can use `\d` to match digits.